# Flutter - Prevent dismissible text from overlapping drawer edge

Tags: android, flutter

When attempting to use `Dismissible`s in a `Drawer`, I noticed that when swiping in the direction of the screen behind the Drawer, the Dismissible's text would overlap onto the background:

[image]

### The code:

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MaterialApp(
    home: TestRoute(),
  ));
}

class TestRoute extends StatefulWidget {
  _RouteState createState() => _RouteState();
}

class _RouteState extends State<TestRoute> {
  
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext ctx) {
    List sampleList = ["Sample Text"];
    return Scaffold(
        drawer: Drawer(
          child: ListView.builder(
            itemCount: sampleList.length,
            itemBuilder: (context, index) {
              return Dismissible(
                  secondaryBackground: Container(
                      alignment: Alignment.centerRight,
                      child: Icon(Icons.block, color: Colors.white, size: 30),
                      color: Colors.red,
                      padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(0, 0, 20, 0)),
                  background: Container(
                      alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
                      child: Icon(Icons.check_rounded,
                          color: Colors.white, size: 30),
                      color: Colors.green,
                      padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(20, 0, 0, 0)),
                  key: Key(sampleList[index].toString()),
                  child: ListTile(
                    leading: Icon(Icons.mail_outline),
                    title: Text(sampleList[index].toString()),
                  ));
            },
          ),
        ),
        drawerEnableOpenDragGesture: false,
        body: Builder(
            builder: (context) => Container(
                    child: Column(
                        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                        children: [
                      Row(
                        children: [
                          Padding(
                              padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(5, 40, 0, 0),
                              child: RawMaterialButton(
                                  onPressed: () {
                                    Scaffold.of(context).openDrawer();
                                  },
                                  child: Icon(Icons.notifications,
                                      size: 48, color: Colors.black))),
                        ],
                      )
                    ]))));
  }
}
```

Is there any way I can disable the text's overlap?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I got same issue.
You can wrap your Dismissible with ClipRect.

```
return ClipRect(
   child: Dismissible(...),
)
```

Comment: Thanks! I'll try it out when I get the chance :^)